# getting Undefined property: stdClass::$insertion when try to parse JSON array

Tags: php, json, parsing

i have this json on which i try to extract the insertion-orders array

```
{
    "response" : {
        "status" : "OK",
        "count" : 1,
        "insertion-orders" : [{
                "id" : 5,
                "name" : "First Choice",
                "code" : null,
                "state" : "active",
                "line_items" : [{
                        "id" :352,
                        "timezone" : "Europe/London"
                    }, {
                        "id" :358,
                        "timezone" : "Europe/London"
                    }
                ],
                "labels" : null,
                "safety_pacing" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what im doing is TheJson is the json string:

```
$Json = json_decode($TheJson);
$JsonResponse = $Json->response;
$OrdersArray = $JsonResponse->insertion-orders;
```

the error im getting is :

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$insertion in /home/foo/a/foo.com/user/htdocs/FunctionManager.php on line 16

Notice: Use of undefined constant orders - assumed 'orders' in /home/foo/a/foo.com/user/htdocs/FunctionManager.php on line 16
```

line 16 is :

```
 $OrdersArray = $JsonResponse->insertion-orders;
```

i just don't get it , its valid json

Comment: But its not valid PHP

Comment: Use `$JsonResponse->{'insertion-orders'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$JsonResponse->insertion-orders;
```

is parsed as

```
$JSonResponse->insert MINUS orders
```

You can't use `-` in an object attribute name using the arrow notation. It'll have to be

```
$JsonResponse->{'insertion-orders'}
```

instead.

As for your comment about it being valid JSON, it wouldn't have worked in Javascript either:

```
json.insertion-orders
```

will also be seen as `json.insertion MINUS orders`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use array notation with objects in PHP?

Comment: i think it would be possible to do `$JsonResponse->{"insertion-orders"}` but a better idea may be to pass true as the second argument to the json_decode and deal with it as an array.

Comment: Right. Brainfart on my part and mixing up JS/php. Edited the answer.

Comment: but in js it is valid to day json["insertion-orders"]

Comment: +1 for explaining why the original code fails, even though you were slow to post the right solution.